# Removing dynamic form element with jquery validation rules

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have created a HTML form where users can dynamically add and remove input fields.

#### Update (again)

After <strike>wasting</strike> investing :) a few more hours on this problem I can replicate this issue/bug/error in a very simple example. I'm not sure how to debug any more than this. You will need the latest version of jquery validate and unobtrusive validation.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Content/scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Content/scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Content/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        Click me to remove: <input type="checkbox" id="chkTest" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("input#chkTest").click(function () {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Click the checkbox and you will get the error:

> Error: Unable to get value of the property 'nodeName': object is null or undefined

Comment: What is the value of $parent after looking for `.closest('tr')`?

Comment: What is your HTML? have you tied `$(this).parents('tr:first').remove();`

Comment: @Kerry I've posted my HTML and a big more information. But to answer your question I get the same error.
@natedavisolds - $parent is not null if that's the question. Please see my updates to the question.

Comment: As opposed to using clone, try just appending or setting the html

Comment: Yet another update. You should be able to replicate now.

Comment: I've found that if I call event.stopPropagation() in the click event it prevents the error from occurring. I wouldn't say this is the "fix" though - shouldn't jquery validate handle elements being removed and detach any handlers/validation?

Comment: Thank you! You've just solved my problem! I'm glad that I looked at the comments. May be you should put this into an answer?